# Does SOLR remove rows from index if they are not returned by deltaImportQuery?

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a SOLR instance that is updated using `deltaQuery`/`deltaImportQuery`.
There is a row in SOLR that was changed in the source database table since last SOLR update.

During the next update `deltaQuery` returns primary key of this row (because it was changed recently). `deltaImportQuery` should select data for the particular primary key. This query contains additional filter on some field like `IsSearchableItem=1` (I don't want to make searchable some rows).

So, `deltaImportQuery` does not return any data for the row (this particular row `IsSearchable=0`). Will this row be removed from SOLR index in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe if DIH does not generate a replacement document (I think what you call row), it will not get deleted. Instead, you could look at checking for using $deleteDocById when IsSearchableItem is 1. Check $skipDoc usage in [Wikipedia dump example](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Example%3a_Indexing_wikipedia).

Or use [deletedPkQuery](http://solr.pl/en/2011/01/03/data-import-handler-%E2%80%93-removing-data-from-index/).